# Smugmug uploading image API v2 using PHP & Curl

Tags: php, curl, upload

Im trying to upload an image to Smugmug using the Upload API v2.
I've been trying for quite a time but it wont work.
This is what i've came up with so far.

When i run the script the response is as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: private, no-store, no-cache, max-age=1, must-revalidate Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 Date: Tue, 07 Jul 2015 14:18:50 GMT Edge-Control: no-store Expires: Tue, 07 Jul 2015 14:18:50 GMT Server: nginx X-Powered-By: SmugMug/1.0 X-SmugMug-Hiring: How to love what you do: http://www.smugmug.com/jobs/ X-SmugMug-Values: 1/4 - Thrill your customers Content-Length: 38 Connection: keep-alive
```

But the file isn't uploaded..
Do you see anything wrong with the code?

```
    include_once("oauth/OAuth.php");
    include_once("constants.php");

    $access_token = '***';
    $access_token_secret = '***';

    $consumer = new OAuthConsumer(API_KEY, API_KEY_SECRET);
    $signature_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_PLAINTEXT;

    $token = new OAuthToken($access_token, $access_token_secret);

    $req_token = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, $token, "POST", 'http://upload.smugmug.com');
    $req_token->sign_request($signature_method, $consumer, $token);
    $parameters = $req_token->get_parameters();

    $path = 'image.png';
    $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $data = file_get_contents($path);
    $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);

    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $path);
    finfo_close($finfo);


    $header[] = 'Authorization: OAuth realm="http://upload.smugmug.com/",
                 oauth_consumer_key='.$parameters['oauth_consumer_key'].',
                 oauth_token='.$parameters['oauth_token'].',
                 oauth_signature_method='.$parameters['oauth_signature_method'].',
                 oauth_signature='.$parameters['oauth_signature'].',
                 oauth_timestamp='.time().',
                 oauth_nonce='.md5(time() . mt_rand()).',
                 oauth_version=1.0';

    $body[] = 'Accept: application/json';
    $body[] = 'X-Smug-Version: v2';
    $body[] = 'X-Smug-ResponseType: JSON';
    $body[] = 'X-Smug-AlbumUri: /api/v2/album/******';
    $body[] = 'X-Smug-Filename: image.png';
    $body[] = 'Content-MD5: '.$base64.'';
    $body[] = 'Content-Length: '.filesize($path).'';
    $body[] = 'Content-Type: '.$mime.'';




    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://upload.smugmug.com/');    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body); 
    curl_error ($ch);



    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using OAuth can be tricky, and the upload API for SmugMug is a little unique. It might be helpful to use one of the PHP wrappers out there rather than write your own code. Here are two, both of which have examples of how to upload images:

1.) [phpSmug](http://phpsmug.com/)

2.) [DFM Smug Wrapper](https://github.com/dfmedia/dfm-smug-wrapper)

For example with the DFM Smug Wrapper, you can do the following (copied from the README file included with the wrapper):

```
<?php
require_once("dfm-smug-wrapper/dfm-smug-wrapper.php");
$f = new DFM_Smug(
       "oauth_consumer_key=12345678",
       "oauth_secret=some_secret",
       "token_id=12345",
       "token_secret=some_other_secret",
       "app_name=My Cool App/1.0 (http://app.com)",
       "api_ver=2.0"
  );
$f->images_upload("AlbumID=123456", "File=/path/to/image.jpg");
?>
```